# class not found when sharing test setup

Tags: symfony, phpunit, functional-testing

I'm doing some functional testing with phpunit and guzzle inside a Symfony 3.2 application.

I have multiple tests that need to load a database and login to an application before the tests run. This is set up like this:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Legacy\Functional;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;

class UsersTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    protected function setUp()
    {
        self::bootKernel();
        $dir = self::$kernel->getRootDir()."/../Tests/Legacy/Functional";
        exec('mysql < '.$dir.'/pagesTestData.sql');
    }

    protected function getCookieJar()
    {
        static $jar;
        if (!isset($jar)){
            $jar = new CookieJar;
        }
        return $jar;
    }

    protected function getClientAndLogin()
    {
        $client = new Client([
            'base_uri' => 'http://functionaltest.thesite.example.com',
            'cookies' => $this->getCookieJar()
        ]);

        $loginPageResponse = $client->get('/index.php');
        $csrf = [];
        preg_match('#<input type="hidden" name="X-XSRF-TOKEN" value="(.*?)" />#ism', $loginPageResponse->getBody(), $csrf);

        if ($csrf[1]){
            $loginData = [
                'email_address' => 'test@example.com',
                'password' => 'secure',
                'X-XSRF-TOKEN' => $csrf[1],
                'start' => 'Start!'
            ];
            if ($client->post('/index.php', [
                'form_params' => $loginData,
                'cookies' => $this->getCookieJar()
            ])){
                return $client;
            }else{
                throw new \Exception('Test login failed');
            }
        }else{
            throw new \Exception('Csrf not enabled');
        }
    }

    public function testUsers()
    {
        $client = $this->getClientAndLogin();
        //actual test and 
    }
}
```

My phpunit.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.8/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="var/bootstrap.php.cache"
>
    <php>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
        <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="app/" />
    </php>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>Tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory>src/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>src/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

When I extract setup() and getClientAndLogin() into a separate file and class "FunctionalShared" in the same folder, this is not found:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: jochen
 * Date: 6/01/17
 * Time: 11:19 AM
 */

namespace Tests\Legacy\Functional;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;

class FunctionalShared extends KernelTestCase
{
    protected function setUp()
    {
        ...

    protected function getCookieJar()
    {
        ...
    protected function getClientAndLogin()
    {
        ...

class UsersTest extends FunctionalShared
{

/usr/bin/php /tmp/ide-phpunit.php --bootstrap /home/jochen/projects/zog2017/system/var/bootstrap.php.cache --configuration /home/jochen/projects/zog2017/system/phpunit.xml Tests\Legacy\Functional\UsersTest /home/jochen/projects/zog2017/system/Tests/Legacy/Functional/UsersTest.php
Testing started at 11:24 AM ...
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Tests\Legacy\Functional\FunctionalShared' not found in /home/jochen/projects/zog2017/system/Tests/Legacy/Functional/UsersTest.php on line 17
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /tmp/ide-phpunit.php:0
PHP   2. IDE_Base_PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /tmp/ide-phpunit.php:587
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /tmp/ide-phpunit.php:299
PHP   4. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->getTest() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:149
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->loadSuiteClass() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php:102
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Runner_StandardTestSuiteLoader->load() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php:168
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::checkAndLoad() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Runner/StandardTestSuiteLoader.php:77
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::load() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php:76
PHP   9. include_once() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php:92

Process finished with exit code 255
```

Comment: kinda late a bit )) how do you manage loading classes? Do you have some kind of autoloader for your test-zone classes?

Comment: yes, just the Symfony 3.2 autoloader

Comment: Personally, i never use those (although i've just looked up on sources -- there is nothing special there except for one slight thing), besides it's unclear from your code samples where and when the autoloader is run and how it is configured. But obviously it is unaware of `Tests\Legacy\Functional\FunctionalShared` at the moment when it should be. Still, if you claim that `Tests\Legacy\Functional\UsersTest` does work (unextracted), meaning that autoloader is aware of `Tests\Legacy\Functional` namespace, my guess there's a typo or smth missing in either namespace declaration or file name/path

Answer (score 0):

In the `UsersTest` file you need to use the `FunctionalShared` class at the very beginning:

```
<?php
...
use Tests\Legacy\Functional\FunctionalShared;

class UsersTest extends FunctionalShared  
{
...
```

If you take a look at #5 in this [Testing Setup Tutorial](http://intelligentbee.com/blog/2016/03/11/setup-testing-and-fixtures-in-symfony2-the-easy-way/), you can see an example on how to properly extend a class.

Comment: I had this in there, sorry for not copying this properly over to my question. However I still cannot get it going in the test folder. However when I copy the whole setup over to AppBundle/src/Tests it works

Comment: Oh, ok. Then the issue might be related to how Symfony organises its bundles.